# Jenkins is failing at the Pre Set Up stage: "No space left on device"? All I did was change a comment in the code

Tags: docker, github, jenkins, diskspace

So I have been pushing my branches to Github, and recently I have run into the following build fail:
[image]

The strange thing is that Jenkins was passing just a minute ago, and since then all I did was change a comment.

My question is, is the above error to do with my local disk space or docker disk space that is on Github (i.e. nothing to do with my local machine)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the master node to run your pipeline: Master node has no space left

Assuming you're using worker nodes: Worker node has no space left